# ng2-datepicker with format option and ngModel returning [object Object]

Tags: angular, ng2-datepicker

I'm trying to use the ng2-datepicker for choosing a date and afterwards displaying it on a table. I'm having the issue that the binding to my chosen date doesn't work. I guess that it has to do something with the format option that I made (DD.MM.YYYY). In my html, I have this code:

```
<ng2-datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" [options]="datepickeroptions"></ng2-datepicker>
```

datepickeroptions with typescript is like this:

```
this.datepickeroptions = {
  format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
  locale: "de",
};
```

I tried to initialize the date variable as Date and as string, but none of them worked. I get just [object Object] as value from ngModel although the value in the input container looks ok. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: object Object in parent container]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I came to a solution! At first I found out that the json pipe gave me the right properties. Then I created a deadlineinput on my .ts file of type any and initialized it like this in the OnInit:

```
 this.deadlineinput = {
        formatted: ''
    };
```

here, one could also add the other options he wants to access (the json 
and on the html looks like this:

```
{ "day": "05", "month": "01", "year": "2017", "formatted": "05.01.2017", "momentObj": "2017-01-04T23:00:00.000Z" }
```

I put this on the .hmtl:

```
<ng2-datepicker [(ngModel)]="deadlineinput" [options]="datepickeroptions"></ng2-datepicker> <label> selected date is: {{deadlineinput.formatted}} </label>
```

I know that it shouldn't be like this, and I opened an Issue for the current version on github, but at least it's a workaround which helps me for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use banana box notation instead to use only box:

```
[(ngModel)]="date"
```

- (): from view to control data bind
- []: from control to view data bind
- [()]: 2 way data bind

Comment: Sorry, this was a mistake because of trying around or copying. In my project is the banana box notation and still doesn't work. I adapted the code above. Could it be anything else?

Comment: Just tried to comment out the options and everything additionally, I even copied the example from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker but it doesn't work, I always get "object Object" with "Option A" explained on the page. Does it work for anybody?